# Downloading all files in each resivision from a SVN repo using SVNkit - Please HELP

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

Here is my problem:

I am working on a project as part of my diploma thesis. I am trying to connect to different Open Source project repositories and get info from source files. Actually we analyze the code of this projects and the changes made on it during the time. In other words, we want to see how the software evolves and specify the changes made on. Therefore, we need to connect to a repository using SVNKit and download for each source file its contents for each revision it is changed.

For example let say we have a project with an initial directory structure:

- dirA/

  -- file1.java

  -- file2.java

The first commit make changes to dirA/file1.java and the second to dirA/file2.java and file1.java. We want to analyze the code of two files (file1.java and file2.java) at initial state and then the changes that were made at file1.java during first and second commit and the changes made at file2.java during second commit.

The third commit creates directories and files:

- dirB/

  -- file3.java
- dirA/dirC

  -- file4.java

In the same way as described above we want to analyze the code for dirB/file3.java and dirA/dirC/file4.java, as well as we want to analyze how the (main) directory structure is changed.

The 4th commit copies the file file3.java to dirA/dirC/ directory and makes changes to this file. In the same way we want to analyze how the copy operation changed the directory structure and analyze the contents of file3.java before and after the commit.

Because we are code oriented we want to get all of the source files from repository and all their revisions. For each  revision of a particular file we want the contents of current revision (starting from very first revision) and the previous one, until the last revision. Because a file is not necessary changed at each commit (it might be copied or deleted) there is no need to download a duplicate file with same contents.

I know there is a way to retrieve the original state of a file only by having its contents at its last revision by recursively performing backward diff to its contents. For example having the contents of dirA/file1.java at last revision (the one created during second commit) and having the diff output we can retrieve the state of file as it was before this revision (before second commit). This way there is no need to download each file's contents for each revision. So we only have to download the contents of a file at the very first revision and then every diff output (if any) for each revision and perform forward diff to retrieve the state after commit.

Explanation :

1 - at revision 1 file1.java has this content:

```
"Content at revision 1 (initial state)"
```

2 - at revision 2 this file is modified to, and has the following content:

```
"Content at revision 1 (initial state)
 Modification at revision 2 (line added)"
```

3 - at revision 3 this file is modified to and has the following content:

```
"Modification at revision 2 (line added)
 Modification at revision 3 (line added)
 First line from revision 1 was removed"
```

If we get logs for file1.java we will have three entries, one for each modification (which corresponds to rev 1, 2, 3). For all three revisions we want to retrieve file contents, because we analyze code modification each time a commit (change) is made for a source file.
We know how to do it in a simple way: SVNRepository.getFile(...). The problem with this approach is, if we have 1 file which has been modified 1000 we have to download its contents 1000 times (each time for a different rev number). That is, for a small project with 100 source files and approximately 1000 modifications per each file we should get 100,000 different contents!!! An other approach is to get the contents of the file for the very last revision and for each previous revision to get the diff output. Than we can apply diff output (backwardly) to retrieve the contents of the file for all previous revisions. That is, we minimize bandwidth.
This is a solution I am looking for, or if there is a better solution you are pleased to contribute.

Can you please provide me some help on how to implement such functionality with SVNKit. It would be very useful if you provide some short code example, and or which classes and methods I have to use, so I can read the java doc. Every help will be appreciate.

Thank you in advance, 
Elvis.

Answer (score 1):

Run the log/revision history. Start at the beginning of the project, and look at the modified files in each commit. When you see a file change/add/delete/copy/move (you can see this in the commit info), download the file contents for that revision, and remember it for the next time you see that file change. Then you've only got the files contents at each change.

Have you seen the SVN kit examples / tutorial?

- http://wiki.svnkit.com/Printing_Out_File_Contents
- http://wiki.svnkit.com/Printing_Out_Repository_History

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I have already seen those examples. And I know how to get file contents for a specific revision (SVNRepository.getFile(...)). My problem is very specific: let say we have a file at revision 100000 and it was present since 0 revision. What we want is to get contents of this file for each revision it is modified. As it is stated in above example: we want the contents of file1.java (see ex. above) before first commit, and the contents after first commit, and the contents afters second commit.

Comment: That's why you run the log/revision history. Start at the beginning of the project, and look at the modified files in each commit. When you see a file change, download that revision's contents, and remember it for the next time you see that file change. Then you've only got the files contents at each change.

Comment: Daniel thank you again for you reply and sorry for being too late. I have some questions:

Comment: Daniel thank you again for you reply and sorry for being too late. I have some questions: 1) What do you mean "at the beginning of te project"? Do you mean the first revision the project was created? If so how can I find that revision? 2) How to discover file changes? Is  that by seeing path type of log entry (which in this case would be SVNLogEntryPath.TYPE_MODIFIED)? (continues...)

Comment: 3) What if I have a project which has 1000 source files and each file is modified approximately 100 times. In this case I have to call 100.000 SVNRepository.getFile(...) and this is not very efficient. I know another solution to minimize bandwidth by getting each time only diff delta but the problem still exists there should be 100.000 calls for this. Is there any other method like List<Delta> getDeltasForRevisionRange(String path, long startR, long endR). In case there is such method then only 1000 times would be calling.

Comment: 1) Yes, the first commit. In subversion commit #1 will be the first.
2) I think so.
3) Don't worry about it now. It's not worth spending an extra week coding something that only might save you 10-20 minutes to download a project.

Comment: Thank you for you replay. Ok I think I found a solution in case someone is going to need it. Here it is:

Comment: 1) For a project at ../../myproject point SVNRepository to that location (setLocation()).

Comment: 2) Get current directory tree. U can discover directory tree by running SVNRepository.status() there is a very good example at their site. 3) Donwload all logs for all paths of that project (SVNRepository.log() where start revision = 0 and endRevision = -1). 3) For each file path we got at second step do download all revision at once: SVNRepository.getFileRevisions, where the first revision can be 0 and the last should be the revision that has the log (previously downloaded) of that path where the path is modified (not DELETED). So this way we only have to make connection per each file.